# How to use ajax to set the src of an image?

Tags: html, ajax, image, jqxhr

I need to set some headers when getting an image. The `img` `src` attribute does not allow this, so I'm using an XHR request to get the image. However, when I set the `src` attribute on the `img` tag after that request completes, it looks like the request is triggered again. Is there a way to cache the image and not trigger the second request?

Sample Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var url = 'https://i.imgur.com/bTaDhpy.jpg'
    var file = $.get(url);
    file.then(function(data) {
        $('#foo').attr('src', url);
    });
});
```

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mehulkar/o4Lcs5Lo/

**Note**: my question is *not* about how to set the appropriate headers in the xhr request. My question is how to not trigger another GET from the setting of the `src` attribute and use the response from the XHR to display the image.

Comment: just do this ``$('#foo').attr('src', 'https://i.imgur.com/bTaDhpy.jpg');`` and you are good to go!

Comment: He needs headers, so he needs XHR. He also needs the image as an `<img>`, so he needs `src`. I'm afraid you'll have to let the browser handle caching.

Comment: You could use the XHR's response to make a data URL... =) Or not: https://jsfiddle.net/rudiedirkx/o4Lcs5Lo/1/ See http://stackoverflow.com/a/28973694/247372 for native XHR's 'arraybuffer' response type

Answer (score 3):

Use the [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) for this:

```
var myImg = $('#foo'),
    mySrc = 'https://i.imgur.com/bTaDhpy.jpg';

$.ajax({
    url: mySrc,
    type: "GET",
    headers: {
        "X-TOKEN": 'xxxxx'
    }
}).done(function() {
    myImg.attr('src', mySrc);   // set the image source
}).fail(function() {
    myImg.hide();    // or something other
});
```

Comment: Setting to `src` attribute will trigger another GET request (as my example jsfiddle shows), at least in Chrome.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/12714338/1295622. May you can combine both answers.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment here due to reputation points, but here is what I've found on this.
I have a local html page that I'm executing via file:///
I can use a $.get to dynamically pull svg files into a variable. The debugger shows this as if it were a standard html node `<svg`. (I'm using Firefox Developer, but also in Firebug I see the svg file as a node.).

So At this point I have an empty `<img` that I want to set to my svg file I just don't know how to set the src attribute to the actual document itself. I suppose I could encode to base64.. You might be able to set it using the debugger itself. I couldn't get this to work reliably. Another avenue (for me since I'm using svg) is to clone the object then write it node for node. If you're not using svg perhaps there is some similar hack you could conduct with canvas? Load the image as a sprite then read the colors and set pixels?