# How to embed base64 encoded data in image after downloading data from Azure Blob Storage in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, base64, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to embed an image using the base64 data pattern, instead of a URL reference. I first download the data from Azure Blob storage, using the Azure Node.js SDK:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-nodejs-how-to-use-blob-storage/#download-blobs

From what I can tell the data downloads as a string. But I'm not sure what to do with the string to get it into base64.

I need to encode the data as base64 and set the image source attribute. How do I do that?

Here is a snippet that shows what happens when I try to just embed the downloaded data directly:

```
        cameraContainer.listBlobsSegmentedWithPrefix($routeParams.cameraId, path, null, options, function(error, result, response) {
        result.entries.forEach(function(entry) {
            $http.get(containerUrl + "/" + $routeParams.cameraId + "/" + entry.name + containerToken)
                .then(function(successResponse) {
                    $scope.camera.imageUrl = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + successResponse.data;
                }, function(errorResponse) {

                });
        });
    });
```

I end up getting this error in the browser:

[image]

Also, if I try executing the following JS:

```
console.log(decodeURIComponent(successResponse.data));
```

I get this error:

[image]

[Here is the raw data when logging to console](https://skyproslrsjc001.blob.core.windows.net/public/localhost-1473124511460.log)

Comment: _"From what I can tell the data downloads as a string"_ Is the data already a `base64` string? Can you include downloaded data string at Question?

Comment: I added a code snippet and error screenshot to show more specifically what I'm seeing from Javascript.

Comment: What does `console.log(decodeURIComponent(successResponse.data))` log at `console`?

Comment: Looks like the decodeURIComponent function doesn't recognize that format as a URL - see updated screenshots. Also, something I noticed is that the image is downloading as gzip encoding. Do you think I need first Decompress it?

Comment: Is there an option to set `successResponse.data` to a `Blob` instead of an encoded string?

Comment: I'm not sure. I'm using Angular JS, the $http docs talk about a "Transforming Requests and Responses". Is that what your talking about? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: Can you include the full `successResponse.data` string at as text Question? Cannot view entire string at image currently posted at Question

Comment: I added a log of console output. It was too much data for the post, so I uploaded a file you can download, see link at end of post.

Comment: You're getting back binary data. I believe you would need to convert that into base64 string.

Comment: Could you provide the code snippet in your Node.js side which to show how to download the blobs and respond for your client side?

Comment: @GauravMantri that's what I need some help with, how do I convert the binary data to base64 in Javascript?

Comment: Added an answer with the code that we're using for doing exact same thing (downloading blob via JS and displaying them inline). Give it a try. HTH.

Comment: I found the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23013871/how-to-parse-into-base64-string-the-binary-image-from-response

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it in our product. Please give it a try.

Essentially the data you're getting back is `Uint8Array`. First thing you would need to do is convert that array into string. You can use the following code to do so:

```
function Uint8ToString(array) {
    var chunkSize = 0x8000;
    var c = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i += chunkSize) {
        c.push(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, array.subarray(i, i + chunkSize)));
    }
    return c.join('');
}
```

Next, you need to convert this string in base64 format. Here's how I'm doing it currently:

```
var blobContentsAsString = Uint8ToString(blobContents); 
var blobContentsAsBase64String = btoa(blobContentsAsString);
$scope.camera.imageUrl = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + blobContentsAsBase64String;
```

Do give it a try.

Comment: Tried it, got this error: 'angular.js:12520 TypeError: array.subarray is not a function'

Comment: Also when I try ' console.log(successResponse.data instanceof Array);' i get 'false' so it looks like the data is not in the form of an array?

Comment: Can you try getting the type of response data? Do something like `console.log(typeof successResponse.data)`.

Comment: The response is 'string'

Comment: Also do you think that the fact that the images are Gzip'd could have something to do with this? Does the browser automatically decompress the image or do I have to do that in Javascript?

Comment: I believe you would need to do that in JavaScript.