# How ro convert html to base64 by using getContext?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group form-md-line-input" style="">
    <input type="text" class="form-control calculator" id="form_control_1" name="unit_11" onchange="barcode_update()">
        <label for="form_control_1">Pc</label>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
var html = $(".form-group.form-md-line-input");
var image = html.getContext('2d');
```

Anyone can please help me How can I convert HTML to base64 string?

Comment: Take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23013871/how-to-parse-into-base64-string-the-binary-image-from-response

Comment: Why you would convert HTML to base64 with getContext ?? what are you trying to do ? the getContext method is only available for Canvas elment