# Use the base64 preview of the binary data response (zip file) in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I always get this error in the downloaded zip file `C:\Users\me\Downloads\test.zip: Unexpected end of archive`

My current code is:

```
var blob = new Blob([data], { // data here is the binary content
    type: 'octet/stream',
});
var zipUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
var fileName = orderNo;
fileName += '.zip';
downloadFile(null, fileName, null, zipUrl, null); // just creates a hidden anchor tag and triggers the download
```

The response of the call is a binary (I think). [Binary Content Here](https://pastebin.com/uueRgQWb)

But the preview is a base64. [Base64 Content](https://pastebin.com/aQimdF8b). And it is the correct one. The way I verify it is by using this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VB59f/544/).

You can refer to the screenshot of the network [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHhem.jpg)

I put the base64 content in this line `var sampleBytes = base64ToArrayBuffer('');` And the zip downloaded just opens fine.

Things I have tried so far.

1. Adding this headers to the GET call

   var headers = {
       Accept: 'application/octet-stream',
       responseType: 'blob',
   };
   But I get `Request header field responseType is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.`

We're using an already `ajax.service.js` in our AngularJS project.

2. [From this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23452051/4620773)

`var blob = new Blob([yourBinaryDataAsAnArrayOrAsAString], {type: "application/octet-stream"});
var fileName = "myFileName.myExtension";
saveAs(blob, fileName);`

There are other things that I have tried that I have not listed. I will edit the questions once I find them again

But where I'm current at right now. The `preview` is correct base64 of the binary file. Is it possible to use that instead of the binary? (If it is I will not find the other methods that I've tested) I tried some `binary to base64` converters but they don't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I just went and ditched using the `ajax.service.js`, that we have, for this specific call.

I used the `xhr` snippet from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29473727/4620773). I just added the headers necessary for our call: tokens and auth stuff.

And I used [this code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23451803/4620773) for the conversion thing.

And the code  looks like this:

```
fetchBlob(url, function (blob) {
    // Array buffer to Base64:
    var base64 = btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(blob)));
    var blob = new Blob([base64ToArrayBuffer(base64)], {
        type: 'octet/stream',
    });
    var zipUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    var fileName = orderNo;
    fileName += ' Attachments ';
    fileName += moment().format('DD-MMM-YYYY');
    fileName += '.zip';
    downloadFile(null, fileName, null, zipUrl, null); // create a hidden anchor tag and trigger download
});

function fetchBlob(uri, callback) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', uri, true);
    xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
    var x = AjaxService.getAuthHeaders();
    xhr.setRequestHeader('auth_stuff', x['auth_stuff']);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('token_stuff', x['token_stuff']);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/octet-stream');

    xhr.onload = function (e) {
        if (this.status == 200) {
            var blob = this.response;
            if (callback) {
                callback(blob);
            }
        }
    };

    return xhr.send();
};

function base64ToArrayBuffer(base64) {
    var binaryString = window.atob(base64);
    var binaryLen = binaryString.length;
    var bytes = new Uint8Array(binaryLen);
    for (var i = 0; i < binaryLen; i++) {
        var ascii = binaryString.charCodeAt(i);
        bytes[i] = ascii;
    };

    return bytes;
}
```

Comment: ... XHR.responseType also accepts a `"blob"` value, which will... return a Blob as the `response`, and get rid of your horrible AB to b64 to AB to Blob.

Comment: I will try that one out. The above answer is the first one that I got working