# Converting array buffer to string - Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, binary

Our app downloads a zip file, but the response is in binary.

So what I did is to convert it to base64. It works when the size is `87.7KB` but an error occurs when the response size is `183KB`.

The error is `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

The line in question is

```
btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(blob)))
```

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38437518/4620773), the `String.fromCharCode.apply()` must be replaced with `TextEncoder`.

So I changed it to

```
btoa(new TextDecoder('utf-8').decode(new Uint8Array(blob)))
```

but I get an error.

`Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'btoa' on 'Window': The string to be encoded contains characters outside of the Latin1 range.`

I changed it again using the top most snippet of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26603875/4620773)

The new code is now

```
btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(new TextDecoder('utf-8').decode(new Uint8Array(blob)))))
```

The download now works but the download zip file is corrupted.

The whole code can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49054377/4620773)

Comment: I already posted a comment on your previous answer, but this is an X-Y issue, you really don't need to go through b64, not even through AB.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I got my answer from another question

```
btoa(new Uint8Array(blob).reduce(function (data, byte) {
    return data + String.fromCharCode(byte);
}, ''));
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42334410/4620773)

Comment: this code gets rid of maximum stack size error, but i am using this converted string to generate url which i can use in my embed element as src. But it gives me net::ERR_INVALID_URL error. This only happens with the pdf files which were giving stack size exceeded error. Small pdf file works just fine. Please help.

Answer (score -2):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40077712/6582356

```
function blobToB64(data) {
    if ('TextDecoder' in window) {
      // Decode as UTF-8
      var dataView = new DataView(data);
      var decoder = new TextDecoder('utf8');
      return btoa(decoder.decode(dataView));
    } else {
      // Fallback
      return btoa(new Uint8Array(data).reduce((data, byte) =>
        data + String.fromCharCode(byte),
        ''))
    }
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextDecoder

This one is seems to have better performance

Comment: TextDecoder example is incorrect, since it decodes UTF-8:

`blobToB64(new Uint8Array([240, 159, 152, 128]).buffer)`

*Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'btoa' on 'Window': The string to be encoded contains characters outside of the Latin1 range.*

[240, 159, 152, 128] is code for smiley emoji.

Comment: @dchest agreed, using something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-base64 instead of btoa would fix this