# Converting array buffer to string - Maximum call stack size exceeded - IE

Tags: javascript, binary

The next code returns a `Maximum call stack size` error:

```
var array...
String.fromCharCode.apply(null, array)
```

In [Converting array buffer to string - Maximum call stack size exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49123222/converting-array-buffer-to-string-maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded) there is an answer for Chrome, but I need it for IE.

(IE does not support reduce function)

Comment: IE does support UintArrays though?!

Comment: You right. I edit the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the arry too long.

So in this case I change to native loop and it don't fail to maximum recursive:

```
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
     binaryString += String.fromCharCode(array[i])}
```